# Using single quote when building a string in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, string

I am building a string in Cocoa to be used as a SQL statement which will be passed into the FMDB wrappers for sqlite; however, the database craps out with a BAD_ACCESS failure.  I have the following code:

prefix = @"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1 LIKE '%";

middle = @"%' OR Field2 LIKE '%";

suffix = @"%' ORDERY BY ";

orderby = @"%' ORDER BY Fieldnames";

sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@", prefix, searchString, middle, searchString, suffix, orderby];

At runtime sqlStatement ends up containing something like the following:

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1 LIKE \'%A%\' OR Field2 LIKE \'%A%\' ORDER BY Fieldnames

For some reason a \ is being added into the string which causes the database to bomb out.

Any ideas how I can keep the \ from appearing in my string?

UPDATE:
When I output my variable via NSLog I get the following: 
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1 LIKE 'OX1.87A8013DBD18F-1027' OR Field2 LIKE 'OX1.87A8013DBD18F-1027'ORDER BY Fieldname.

Problem seems to be with using %A in the string.  Even if I hard code the sqlStatement variable to include '%A%' the %A seems to get converted to a memory address or something.  If I do a '%ABAP%' I get the output like 'OX1.87A8013DBD18F-1027BAP'.  Notice i'm losing the % sign.

Comment: What database are you targetting?

Comment: Please edit the original post to format code correctly.

Comment: YOu need to use parameters.  See my post.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess that you're using sqlite, in which case you want to do this slightly differently.  First start by creating your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1 LIKE ?001 OR Field2 LIKE ?002 ORDER BY Fieldnames
```

The ?000 syntax is for parameters.

You can then use sqlite3_bind_text to bind your parameters:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [@"%bar%" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [@"%foo%" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

Hopefully this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your 'update':

It looks like the "%A" is getting used as a format specifier, namely:

> %A: a 64-bit floating-point number (double),
>   printed in scientific notation with a
>   leading 0X and one hexadecimal digit
>   before the decimal point using a
>   uppercase P to introduce the exponent

See [String Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

So what's happening is that you're using the `sqlStatement` string later on as a format control string, which is bad.  If you do need to pass `sqlStatement` to a method/function that interprets the string as a format specifier, you should pass it like `do_query(@"%@", sqlStatement)`

Answer (score 0):

The string seems to be constructed correctly. If I run the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    NSString* prefix = @"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1 LIKE '%";

    NSString* middle = @"%' OR Field2 LIKE '%";

    NSString* suffix = @"%' ORDERY BY ";

    NSString* orderby = @"%' ORDER BY Fieldnames";

    NSString* sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@", prefix, @"blah", middle, @"blah", suffix, orderby];

    NSLog(@"sqlStatement: %@", sqlStatement);

    [pool drain];

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following result in the console:

```
2009-03-05 08:04:29.734 Untitled[79999:813] sqlStatement: SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1 LIKE '%blah%' OR Field2 LIKE '%blah%' ORDERY BY %' ORDER BY Fieldnames
```

Comment: When I output my variable via NSLog I get the following:

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1 LIKE 'OX1.87A8013DBD18F-1027' OR Field2 LIKE 'OX1.87A8013DBD18F-1027'ORDER BY Fieldname.

Problem is searchString.  But when I output that field via NSLog it looks good. \'s only appear in debugger.

Comment: Try your code with an A instead of blah and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "at runtime"?
Do you mean in the Xcode debugger?

Seems you are targeting [this problem](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2007/Mar/msg00875.html).

> The backslash-escaped single quotes
>   only seem to appear inside of the
>   Xcode debugger window's variable
>   summary column. Examining the value of
>   "sql" manually in gdb reveals the
>   correct format:
>
> (gdb) po sql select * from t_state
>   where state_code = 'XX'
>
> and NSLogging the string also leaves
>   out the backslashes. So, I'd say those
>   single quotes are escaped for some
>   reason only in the process of Xcode
>   formatting the object for display in
>   the variable view.

Comment: Then why is sqlite bombing with BAD_ACCESS?